# Dynamic Angular Js Not working via innerHTML

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, innerhtml

If I add a row with Dynamic Angular JS variable, it is not working.
Below is my code. Please help me let know the issue.

Also please note that the inner HTML in my original code is 600 lines long. In this example I have used simple div to simplify.

```
<div data-ng-init="quantity_r=1;price_r=5">
   <h2>Cost Calculator Quantity:</h2>
   <input type="number" ng-model="quantity_r"> Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price_r">
 <div>
Total in dollar: {{quantity_r * price_r}}
 </div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 

</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
 
});

</script>
  <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp1', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
 
 angular.module('ngAppDemo', []).controller('ngAppDemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = 1;
  $scope.b = 2;
});
 
});


function replicateRegion() {
         
         var table = document.getElementById("idTable");
           var lastRow = table.rows.length;

           var row = table.insertRow(lastRow);

           var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
           
         var sHTML =document.getElementById("idTableTD1").innerHTML;
         sHTML=sHTML.replace("_r", "_r" + lastRow.toString());
         sHTML=sHTML.replace("Cost Calculator Quantity:", "Cost Calculator Quantity: Row Added " + lastRow.toString());
            cell1.innerHTML = sHTML;
         
        }

</script>
<div id="id1" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<button onclick="replicateRegion()">insert Row</button>
<table id="idTable">
<tr><td id="idTableTD1">

  
 <div data-ng-init="quantity_r=1;price_r=5">
   <h2>Cost Calculator Quantity:</h2>
   <input type="number" ng-model="quantity_r"> Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price_r">
 <div>
Total in dollar: {{quantity_r * price_r}}
 </div>
  
 
</td></tr>

</table>

</div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Only the first row which is static has the correct output. The rows added after button-click "Insert Row" have the problematic Angular JS output. Please help.

Comment: share you code here.

Comment: Check the answer i have posted. The best way to achieve dynamic dom when using AngularJS.

Comment: Did you looked at the answer? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the code for `replicateRegion()` function inside the AngularJS controller and use the `$compile` service to bind the dynamically generated HTML into the AngularJS DOM.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.controller('AppCtrl', function ($compile, $scope) {
 
   
    $scope.a = 1;
    $scope.b = 2;
    $scope.replicateRegion = function(){
      var table = document.getElementById("idTable");
      var lastRow = table.rows.length;

      var row = table.insertRow(lastRow);

      var template = `<div data-ng-init="quantity_r=1;price_r=5">
               <h2>Cost Calculator Quantity:</h2>
               <input type="number" ng-model="quantity_r"> Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price_r">
             <div>
            Total in dollar: {{quantity_r * price_r}}
             </div>
             </div>`;
  
           var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
         
         template=template.replace(/_r/g, "_r" + lastRow.toString());
         template=template.replace("Cost Calculator Quantity:", "Cost Calculator Quantity: Row Added " + lastRow.toString());
            cell1.innerHTML = template;
          $compile(cell1)($scope); //Now compile it to render the directive.  
    }
        
            
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

 <div id="id1" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<button ng-click="replicateRegion()">insert Row</button>
<table id="idTable">
<tr><td id="idTableTD1">

  
 <div data-ng-init="quantity_r=1;price_r=5">
   <h2>Cost Calculator Quantity:</h2>
   <input type="number" ng-model="quantity_r"> Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price_r">
 <div>
Total in dollar: {{quantity_r * price_r}}
 </div>
 </div>
  
 
</td></tr>

</table>

</div>
```

Also notice that `var template` that specifies a generic template that should be inserted in the HTML dynamically on click. It is always a good practice to specify a static HTML template instead of extracting the generated HTML from the page and using that, which you have done.

Comment: wow. this is great. It works. But in my actual code, the "Template" is very huge. Is there any simple way to copy the innerhtml?

Comment: I thought this could work but not working. character " ` " is invalid for template copy. Did I miss something?

Comment: My dynamic div is very large and it is not possible to give within double quotes. I have only shown a example here with smaller div

Comment: This part is not working....var template = `<div data-ng-init="quantity_r=1;price_r=5">
               <h2>Cost Calculator Quantity:</h2>
               <input type="number" ng-model="quantity_r"> Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price_r">
             <div>
            Total in dollar: {{quantity_r * price_r}}
             </div>
             </div>`;

Comment: Actually visual studio does not allow that character.. Is there any alternative? pls help

Answer (score 0):

When you add markup manually, like

```
document.getElementById('idTableTD1').innerHTML= '<div dynamic></div>'
```

you are bypassing all AngularJS code. You should do it rather as this:

```
angular.element("#idTableTD1").html('<div dynamic></div>');
```

may be this will help.

Comment: My dynamic div is very large and it is not possible to give within double quotes. I have only shown a example here with smaller div.

Comment: It is not actually bypassing angular js code. Problem here is the binding between angular Js and text box is not happening